# AddCardViewController not going away after completion

Tags: ios, swift

I'm pretty new to iOS Programming, and I'm stuck on this little portion here.

I'm basically trying to use Stripe in my iOS application. The user inputs an amount they wish to pay, press NEXT and they input their card details. All of this is going well so far - I can get the AddCardViewController to show up, and input their card details.

The code makes it all the way to verifying the card token and accepting the payment; which is wonderful, but then the problem comes that the AddCardViewController doesn't go away afterward.

When I was trying it out on a demo, it worked perfectly fine, but on my app it doesn't work at all! The app just gets stuck there on the AddCardViewController. Hitting cancel does nothing, there's no display message, and submitting the card details again just double bills the user.

What am I doing wrong?

For further info, this is my code:

```
StripeClient.shared.sendPostRequest(with: token, amount: amount, description: description) { result in
        switch result {
        // 1
        case .success:
            completion(nil)

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Congrats",
                                                    message: "Your payment was successful!",
                                                    preferredStyle: .alert)
            let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            })
            alertController.addAction(alertAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true)

            self.view.makeToast("Your payment was successful! We will be sending you a receipt to your email shortly.")
        // 2
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(error)
        }
    }
```

I made my custom post request because I couldn't get the one offered by the demo to work, but I can say with 100% certainty that the code enters `case .success` successfully - I tested this already. But just in case, this is my .sendPostRequest method:

```
func sendPostRequest(with token: STPToken, amount: Double, description: String, completion: @escaping (Result) -> Void) {
    //declare parameter as a dictionary which contains string as key and value combination. considering inputs are valid

    let params: [String: Any] = [
        "stripeToken": token.tokenId,
        "amount": amount,
        "currency": Constants.defaultCurrency,
        "description": description
    ]

    //create the url with URL
    let url = URL(string: "<this-is-my-url.com>")! //change the url

    //create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared

    //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            //create json object from data
            //print(data)
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                //print(json)
                // handle json...
                //print(json["response"]!)

                if let responseString = try json["response"] as? String {
                    if responseString == "SUCCESS" {
                        completion(Result.success)
                    } else {
                        completion(Result.failure(IntParsingError.overflow))
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

I would really, really, REALLY appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

1- You need

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     completion(Result.success)
}
```

As `session.dataTask(with:` runs in background thread

2- For this to run

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

verify the vc is embedded inside a navigation and you presented it with `push` not `present` func of the previous vc

**Edit:**

When you present do

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer!! But... I'm fairly lost. :s I don't understand what you're getting at at all... i have this part of the code:

`let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addCardViewController)` and `present(navigationController, animated: true)`, which I assume was used to call the AddCardViewController, but I can't replace `present` with `push`.

Comment: replace `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` with the above edit